# What is maximum size of an SQL table resulting from two tables Inner join in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, math, join

Lets take this example:

table **A**

```
Id  Value
x1  v1
x2  v2
.   .
.   .
xN  vN
```

table **B**

```
Id  Id_A
y1  z1
y2  z2
.   .
.   .
yM  zM
```

table **C** = *A Inner join B*

```
Id  Id_A
x1  z_i
x1  z_i
.   .
.   .
xN  z_j
xN  z_j
```

What would be the Maximum size of C in this case? (where I join following the ID of A) 
M can be bigger equal or less than N.

If you can give the formula for the Maximum size for even an lets say T joins then that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's with all the HTML cluttering your table data up? If you were trying to format your data for display here, it won't work. Stackoverflow uses Markdown for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Anyway it's making it quite hard to see the wood for the trees. Please edit your question. Also the "code snippet" thing is unnecessary because your example isn't executable.

Comment: Anyway, what type of JOIN are you referring to? `INNER`, `OUTER`, `FULL` or `CROSS`? And joining on which field(s) (in the case of joins which require that specifying)? That would affect the potential size of the result.

Comment: There are many types of join and the answer depends on which one you are referring to: cross join, left join, inner join, right join, lateral join, union join. Voting to close since the question is unclear.

Comment: It's edited hope it's better now.

Comment: You don't call "inner join" sensibly. And that result is not any SQL join of those inputs. So you're not asking a clear question. PS Please show your research results & attempt at answering. Please don't ask us to do your (home)work. PS This is likely a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2):

The size of an inner join varies between 0 and the product of the rows in the two tables, depending on the matches between the keys:

- `0` when no rows match.
- `n * m` when the join condition always evaluates to true.

(where `n` and `m` are the sizes of the table)

Of course, your sample data suggests that the columns used for the `join` keys are distinct in each table.  In that case (distinct values), the resulting size is no more than the minimum of the sizes of the two tables.

Comment: "the join keys" is unexplained & join keys being "distinct" is unexplained. Whatever you mean, you are not communicating it. Given your last sentence, your "of course" sentence is presumably trying to say something like, that for one of the input tables each row  matches exactly one row from the other table. But what what you wrote doesn't communicate anything, let alone that.